# page size, malloc allocation, and language runtimes

Tags: memory-management, malloc, vm-implementation

Is there any relationship between malloc and the page size (Linux, Windows, Mac)? Can this relationship be exploited for run-time systems that provide memory management themselves (e.g. GC, object allocation, ...)? My guess is that an allocation granularity of `size of page - malloc metadata` might give better performance (cache, swapping), but I do not have evidence for that.

Comment: Memory allocation does not consume any of the page for metadata

Comment: @stark Are you sure? Keep in mind that we're talking `malloc`, not `mmap`. I vaguely recall a malloc implementation that keeps its metadata segregated, but AFAIK many others put it in the allocation.